# Pandas left join - how to replace values not present in second df with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes which I am joining like so:

`df3 = df1.join(df2.set_index('id'), on='id', how='left')`

But I want to replace values for id-s which are present in df1 but not in df2 with `NaN` (left join will just leave the values in df1 as they are). Whats the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: may be not easiest way but you could find those index before merging then replacing in created data frame

Comment: I believe you can use `how='outer'` and missing values will automatically be populated with `nan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1['id'] = df1['id'].where(df1['id'].isin(df2['id']))
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1['id'] = np.where(df1['id'].isin(df2['id']), df1['id'], np.nan)
```

**Sample**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'id':list('abc'),
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'id':list('dmna'),
})

df1['id'] = df1['id'].where(df1['id'].isin(df2['id']))
print (df1)
    id
0    a
1  NaN
2  NaN
```

Or solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) and `indicator` parameter:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left', indicator=True)
df3['id'] = df3['id'].mask(df3.pop('_merge').eq('left_only'))
print (df3)
    id
0    a
1  NaN
2  NaN
```

Comment: I think my question is a bit misleading, what I wanted was to do left join, which would update some values in df1, but if `df1['id']` is not in `df2['id']` then replace value with 'Nan'. But your solution does work, I could just do left join and then do what you suggested to filter out some values